# javascript onclick not working with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I just want the user to click on a name and then it pops (alerts) some info. in the a tag if i don't pass any parameter it does alert something, it otherwise won't alert anything, even if i put something like this

```
<a href='javascript:sayThis('hi');'>
```

here's my html code (generated by some PHP):

PHP:

```
 function showThis($color, $withFunctionYesOrNo, $first_levelIdFunction, $first_levelNameFunction, $first_levelLastNameFunction, $agent_email){
    if($withFunctionYesOrNo == 'yes'){
    $showThis =  "<br>
        <div>
            <div style='margin-left:5%; border-left:6px solid ".$color."'>------
                <a href='javascript:sayThis('".$agent_email."');'>
                ".$first_levelLastNameFunction.", ".$first_levelNameFunction." (ID: ".$first_levelIdFunction.")
                </a>
                <input type='submit' class='more' id='more' value='+' onclick='agentsBelow(".$first_levelIdFunction.")'>
            </div>
        <div style='margin-left:7%;' id=".$first_levelIdFunction."></div>
        </div>";
}
return $showThis;
}
```

here is my JS code:

```
function sayThis(email){
alert(email);
}
```

Comment: <a href='javascript:sayThis('".$agent_email."');'> is error quote. You try <a href='javascript:sayThis(\'".$agent_email."\');'>

Comment: You can't pass any arguments to inline onclick handlers AFAIK (with the exclusion of `this` i think). You'll need to find some other way to access `email`.

Comment: @IvyLynx, as long as the variables are global you can pass them

Comment: @PatrickEvans I guess. I've avoided this for so long I can't remember how it works clearly :P

Comment: You got many solutions check and accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to say that I would never use your coding practice. Not only do you have quote issues all over the place, but `onclick` the Event Object is passed to your Event Handler `agentsBelow()`. In these situations I do my code like this:

```
document.getElementById('more').onclick = function(e){
  e = e || event; // don't even need to use the `e` argument above or this if not using the Event Object
  agentsBelow('whatever');
}
```

Really, the style I'm showing is the way you should code, where your JavaScript is separate from your HTML. Of course, if you insist, you could just wrap your function within an Anonymous function in your HTML. Bad HTML practice:

```
onclick='function(){agentsBelow(\"you have String issues too\")}'
```

Note that you don't need to concatenate in double quotes. By the way:

```
onclick='agentsBelow(".$first_levelIdFunction.")'
```

using bad practice, should be:

```
onclick='function(){agentsBelow(\"$first_levelIdFunction\")}'
```

You are passing a variable to your JavaScript, not a String.

`onclick='agentsBelow(".$first_levelIdFunction.")'` could evaluate to:

```
onclick='agentsBelow(youFirstLevelIdFuntionVarResultIsNotaString)'
```

Still that wouldn't wouldn't work, since the Event Object would pass in.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and the suggestion, I will re-write the code. BTW, it worked using the 'bad practice', but I get what you say... I need to learn way more JS.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
<a href='javascript:sayThis('hi');'>
```

to this:

```
<a href='javascript:sayThis("hi");'>
```

Answer (score -2):

change this

```
<a href='javascript:sayThis('".$agent_email."');'>
```

to

```
<a href='javascript:sayThis(\"".$agent_email."\");'>
```